# remove item from localStorage with a key

Tags: javascript

A user clicks on the switcher and add an item to a localStorage (as you see we add id:coindID every time on click)

If a user decided not to choose it, he clicks again on the switcher, so I wanna remove the item from the localStorage with a localStorage.removeItem(key)

(key is checkedCoins).  But for some reason, it removes everything like clear()

```
    function switchClick(event) {
    
        if(event.target.checked){
            let coinId = event.currentTarget.id;
            const jsonString = localStorage.getItem("checkedCoins")
            if (jsonString) {
                    let cryptoCoins = JSON.parse(jsonString)
                    cryptoCoins.push({id: coinId});
                    let checkedCoinsString = JSON.stringify(cryptoCoins);
                    localStorage.setItem("checkedCoins", checkedCoinsString);  
                    
                    if(cryptoCoins.length > 6 ) {
                        alert("delete")
                    }
            } else {
                localStorage.setItem("checkedCoins", JSON.stringify([{id: coinId}]));  
            }
         } else {
    
           localStorage.removeItem("checkedCoins");
         }
        }
```

Comment: Is there only one key value pair in your localstorage?

Comment: @MohammedShahed to yes and i see it in console something like this: "key: checkedCoins.            value [{"id":"some#"}]

Comment: try `delete localStorage.checkedCoins`

Comment: I guess that your `else` block never runs

Comment: @AjitKumar the same :(

Comment: @KonradLinkowski why it should block it?

Comment: What does a [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) means.

Comment: And what is a "switcher"?

Comment: All your values are stored in one key so if you delete than one key, you are left with no other keys. so the function to remove data works fine, it is just assumption which is wrong. it is actually clearing. Apologies for late reply.

Answer (score 2):

`localStorage.removeItem` means you want to remove the entire object which you keep under that key, but the problem is you have all `checkedCoins` under 1 key only, so that's why it clears all your `checkedCoins` values.

If you want to remove a particular data in `checkedCoins`, you should parse that string to a Javascript object, and use a filter on that object instead.

```
function switchClick(event) {
  let coinId = event.currentTarget.id;
  const jsonString = localStorage.getItem("checkedCoins");
  if (event.target.checked) {
    if (jsonString) {
      let cryptoCoins = JSON.parse(jsonString);
      cryptoCoins.push({ id: coinId });
      let checkedCoinsString = JSON.stringify(cryptoCoins);
      localStorage.setItem("checkedCoins", checkedCoinsString);

      if (cryptoCoins.length > 6) {
        alert("delete");
      }
    } else {
      localStorage.setItem("checkedCoins", JSON.stringify([{ id: coinId }]));
    }
  } else {
    //remove a particular coin in localstorage
    const cryptoCoins = JSON.parse(jsonString);
    const filteredCryptoCoins = cryptoCoins.filter(x => x.id !== coinId);
    localStorage.setItem("checkedCoins", JSON.stringify(filteredCryptoCoins));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could use a localStorage **Array Key** to help with this. This kind of object does not exist natively, but is available in a library such as **[localDataStorage](https://github.com/macmcmeans/localDataStorage)** (of which I am the author).

Here's how I would approach things:

1. Get the library
   *Bring the code into your page via script tags*.

```js
<script
    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/macmcmeans/localDataStorage@master/localDataStorage-3.0.0.min.js" 
    integrity="sha512-dEhk3bL90qpWkcHCJDErHbZEY7hGc4ozmKss33HSjwMeSBKBtiw/XVIE7tb5u+iOEp6dTIR9sCWW7J3txeTQIw==" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
```

2. Instantiate it
   *Create an instance of **localDataStorage** with a meaningful prefix. The "cryptoCoinStorage" constant is your new localStorage object. Data will be stored using the "cryptoCoins" prefix. This is designed to prevent other applications which can access your localStorage from inadvertently messing with your keys*.

```js
const cryptoCoinStorage = localDataStorage( "cryptoCoins" );
```

The response:

```js
>  localDataStorage instantiated. Your specified prefix (**cryptoCoins.**) adds 12 bytes to every key name (stored using 24 bytes).
```

3. Use an **Array Key** in your function to store Coin IDs

```js
const switchClick = function( event ) {
    let coinId = event.currentTarget.id
        , myCheckedCoins = new Array()
    ;

    if ( event.target.checked ) {
        cryptoCoinStorage.push( 'checkedCoins', coinId );
    } else {
        cryptoCoinStorage.pull( 'checkedCoins', coinId );
    }

    myCheckedCoins = cryptoCoinStorage.get( 'checkedCoins' );
}
```

This makes the logic much simpler. All the JSON stringamification is handled by the library, so you don't have to bother with it in your code. Same for the array logic.

The library does much more than this, but I think this covers your use case.